# How to get longitude and latitude of mobile device?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, datasource

I'm working on a project in which I need to find nearest places to the mobile device (Example: display a list of hotels ordered by the nearest first.) I want to get the longitude and latitude of the mobile phone. The problem is that I want to get them in a class that is NOT an activity and it doesn't have a OnCreate method (The datasource class which contains all the methods dealing with the database). What should I write? and where exactly should I write it?

Please keep it simple! Thank you :)

Comment: nothing is stopping you from collecting location data inside your activity or service and passing that to your data base layer

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

The activity would need to pass the context (may require passing the actual activity) to the class. After that you should follow this question as it is essentially a duplicate.

[How do I get the current GPS location programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I use this class to grab location:

```
public class MyLocation {
Timer timer1;
LocationManager lm;
LocationResult locationResult;
boolean gps_enabled=false;
boolean network_enabled=false;

public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
{
    //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
    locationResult=result;
    if(lm==null)
        lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
    try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
    try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

    //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
    if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
        return false;

    if(gps_enabled)
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
    if(network_enabled)
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
    timer1=new Timer();
    timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);
    return true;
}

LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        timer1.cancel();
        locationResult.gotLocation(location);
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
        lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
};

LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        timer1.cancel();
        locationResult.gotLocation(location);
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
        lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
};

class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
         lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

         Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
         if(gps_enabled)
             gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
         if(network_enabled)
             net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

         //if there are both values use the latest one
         if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
             if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                 locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
             else
                 locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
             return;
         }

         if(gps_loc!=null){
             locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
             return;
         }
         if(net_loc!=null){
             locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
             return;
         }
         locationResult.gotLocation(null);
    }
}

public static abstract class LocationResult{
    public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
}
```

}

And to use this class, you can do something like

```
locationResult = new LocationResult() {

public void gotLocation(final Location location) {
latitude = location.getLatitude();
longitude = location.getLongitude();
}
};

myLocation = new MyLocation();
myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);
```